# Can't solve an equation

Tags: equation-solving

Good afternoon. I have such a code, trying to solve an equation:

```
l = 0.01;
a = 0.1;
f[x_] = Sin[Pi*a/l*Sin[x]]/(Pi*a/l*Sin[x]);
Solve[f[x] == 0.7, x]
NSolve[f[x] == 0.7, x]
FindRoot[f[x] == 0.7, {x, 0}]
```

But not `Solve` nor `NSolve` nor `FindRoot` work. Why? What should I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `FindRoot[f[x] == 0.7, {x, 0.1}]`

Comment: `Solve[Rationalize[f[x] == 0.7, 0], x, Reals]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you give `Reals` domain

```
b = 1/100;
a = 1/10;
f[x_] = Sin[Pi*a/b*Sin[x]]/(Pi*a/b*Sin[x]);
Solve[f[x] == 7/10, x, Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
N[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For `c` in integers

Answer (score 4):

To avoid the problem with $\frac{0}{0}$ when $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is evaluated at $x=0$, use [`Sinc`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sinc.html):

```
f[x_]:=Sinc[Pi*a/l*Sin[x]];
```